# Unable to extract certain parameter inside an ng-repeat while using protractor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

Hi my `angular code` is as follows

```
<table class="table">
  <thead><tr>
    <th>Time</th>
    <th>Expression</th>
    <th>Result</th>
  </tr></thead>
  <tr ng-repeat="result in memory">
    <td>
      {{result.timestamp | date:'mediumTime'}}
    </td>
    <td>
      <span>{{result.first}}</span>
      <span>{{result.operator}}</span>
      <span>{{result.second}}</span>
    </td>
    <td>{{result.value}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

My requirement is to obtain the `value` of the `result.first` for the `first element` in the `result` of the `tr` block of my angular code.

My current code to obtain the `value` of the `result.first` for the `first element` in the `result` is as follows

```
var firstResultFirstValue = element(by.repeater('result in memory').row(0).column('result.first')).getText();
```

But I am unable to obtain the `value` of the `result.first` for the `first element` in the `result`. Can somebody tell me as to what I am doing wrong?

**EDIT**
Currently, I solved the problem using the following code

```
var firstResultFirstValue=element(by.css('body > div > table > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(2)')).getText()
```

Comment: you don't have a column for `result.first` here, you have a column with a bunch of `<span>` items in it.

Comment: @Claies can u suggest a solution. I am new to protractor and stuck on this for hours

Comment: I would try to extract the first `span` from `.column(0)` if changing your table to `<td>{{result.first}}</td>` isn't an option.

Comment: @Claies I even tried var firstResultFirstValue = element(by.repeater('result in memory').row(0).column(1).column('result.first')).getText(). Still I am getting an error

Comment: that won't work either, a column is a `td`, not a `span`.